# Assign new key and value to object does not work

Tags: mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

Assign new key and value to object does not work

Here is the post where i would like to add a new key name CreatedUser and wanted to assign object/array but it does not work. Please help on it

here is my code

```
newPost = new PostsModel({
        title,
        content,
        price,
        recreater
      });
    }
    await newPost.save();

     let aggregateMatch = null;
     let user = null;
     if(recreater) {

       aggregateMatch = { $match: { _id: ObjectId(recreater) } };
        user = await UsersModel.aggregate([
       {
         $sort: {
           timestamp: -1
         }
       },
       aggregateMatch
       ])

      newPost.createdUser = user;
     }

    console.log("posts", newPost) //Did not see createdUser key

    res.out(newPost);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add properties to mongoose document. You have to make it native JS object first.

```
const post = newPost.toObject();
post.createdUser = user;
```